# Python casting multiple columns of a list of dataframes

Tags: python, casting, multiple-columns

I have n dataframes in a list and I want to change the type of two specific columns. It is possible to do this with a for loop?

Here's the code:

```
list_of_names = ['BR_youtube_trending_data', 'CA_youtube_trending_data', 'DE_youtube_trending_data', 'FR_youtube_trending_data', 'GB_youtube_trending_data',\
                        'IN_youtube_trending_data', 'JP_youtube_trending_data', 'KR_youtube_trending_data', 'MX_youtube_trending_data', 'RU_youtube_trending_data',\
                            'US_youtube_trending_data']

dataframes_list = []

for i in range(len(list_of_names)):
    temp_df = pd.read_csv("./datasets/"+list_of_names[i]+".csv")
    dataframes_list.append(temp_df)

while len(dataframes_list[i]) < 11:
    for i in dataframes_list[i]:
        dataframes_list[i] = dataframes_list[i].astype({"comments_disabled": str, "ratings_disabled":str})
```

Anyone can explain me why is not working? And if possible, a solution for this problem. Thank you :D

Comment: The loops look weird - what does `i` represent? Reusing it for the loop variable in the last `for` loop will likely cause problems.

Comment: what is your intention with `while len(dataframes_list[i]) < 11`??

Answer (score 0):

```
while len(dataframes_list[i]) < 11:
    for i in dataframes_list[i]:
        dataframes_list[i] = dataframes_list[i].astype({"comments_disabled": str, "ratings_disabled":str})
```

I suspect this is the issue, although I am also somewhat curious why you intentionally use `range(len(list_of_names)):` rather than something like: `for name in list_of_names:`, but thats tangential.

If I have understood your problem correctly, you want to iterate over each DataFrame in the list using a for loop, instead of a while loop but then within the for loop you could use that while loop to append rows to the DataFrame until its length is at least 11, just as you originally intended to do. So something like this perhaps:

```
for df in dataframes_list:
    while len(df) < 11:
        df = df.append(df.iloc[0])
```

Finally you could convert the types, if this is still something you wanted to do, by adding:

```
df = df.astype({"comments_disabled": str, "ratings_disabled": str})
```

at the end of the for loop, **after** the while completes (not inside it).

So it would finally look like:

```
for df in dataframes_list:
    while len(df) < 11:
        df = df.append(df.iloc[0])
    df = df.astype({"comments_disabled": str, "ratings_disabled": str})
```

Comment: `df = df.astype({"comments_disabled": str, "ratings_disabled": str})` this doesn't actualyl modify any of the dataframes in the list

Comment: No, it creates new ones technically :) 

`df.astype({"comments_disabled": str, "ratings_disabled": str}, inplace=True)`

This would modify them in place.

Comment: right, so this doesn't work, you might as well skip all the loops and just do `df = dataframes_list[-1]; df = df = df.astype(...)`